# How to sequentially search for files and save them?

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I have the code below which tries to find PDF files first. If it does not succeed in finding even a single PDF file, then it continues to search for e.g. .TIF files in the same folder.

However, I have two problems. First, when it finds a PDF file in the folder, it also prints all the .TIF files in a .txt file. But when it doesn't find a PDF file, it just stops (even without *break*) and doesn't produce a .txt file. I'm confused and any help is appreciated.

```
b = os.walk('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
os.listdir('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
f = []
for(dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in b:
    if f.extend(os.path.splitext(name)[0] for name in filenames if name.lower().endswith((".pdf"))) == []:
        pass
        break
    elif f.extend(os.path.splitext(name)[0] for name in filenames if name.lower().endswith((".tif"))) == []:
        pass


def save_to_file(text):
    for name in f:
        with open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\test.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            myfile.write('\n'.join(text))
            myfile.write('\n')

save_to_file(f)
```

Comment: `f.extend` always returns `None`, so it has no business in an `if` clause.

Comment: but if I use only name.lower().endswith(..) then it doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

def gather_files(folder, ending):
    contents = os.walk(folder)
    files = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in contents:
        files += ([file.splitext()[0] for file in filenames if file.lower().endswith(ending)])
    return files


def main():
    f = gather_files("test", ".pdf")
    if not f:
        f = gather_files("test", ".tif")

    if not f:
        print("No .pdf or .tif files found in the given directory.")
    else:
        with open("test_out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output:
            output.write("\n".join(f) + "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This should work for you. As an alternative, you could move the the main part to the method gather_files by hard coding values like folder and ending, or you could provide a keyword "alternative_ending" or something like that in the method.

Maybe have another look at your code too. You got a method *save_to_file(text)*, you call it with f, and in it you iterate over f. Probably a typo, you should iterate over text, not f. But you dont need to iterate at all, because text (or f) contains the filenames as a list of strings. So

```
with open("test_out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output:
    output.write("\n".join(text) + "\n")
```

will do everything you want.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, but I can't seem to produce a .txt file with the output? I'm such a noob..

Comment: Are you getting an error? Maybe you don't have write access to the directory you want to write to or something like that?
Remember, if there are no .pdf/.tif files in the folder at all, no .txt-file is created, but the script printd a message.

Comment: Ah never mind, it works. However, I get the extensions now, and if you look at the code I gave, it is with splitext - so it produces a txt file without extensions. But otherwise it works perfectly wow thanks!!

Comment: Check again, I recognized my mistake after posting initially and corrected it - I'm now using splitext, too. You're welcome!

Comment: Haha I guess we solved it at the same time, I wanted to tell you indeed. But thanks very much, this helps me a lot!

And sidenote for future readers: I used the splitext like this and it worked:

 for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in contents:
        files += ([os.path.splitext(file)[0] for file in filenames if file.lower().endswith(".tif")])
    return files

Comment: Glad I could help you.